# Select returns number with e (mathematical constant)

Tags: sql, hive

The field CUSTOMER_BAN is of type double. When I select in HUE it is readable

example

[image]

But when I try to load result of select in a file through CLI, I get

```
CUSTOMER_BAN    count(*)
6.43409603E8    4
6.43411919E8    8
6.44484716E8    20000
6.44874103E8    10
6.44904516E8    10
6.45158643E8    10
6.4535095E8     7
6.45543925E8    10
```

I thought this

```
select concat(CUSTOMER_BAN) as CUSTOMER_BAN
```

will return a string, but the result was the same. How do I get the part before the dot as a string?

```
round(CUSTOMER_BAN)
```

returned the same result.

Comment: Storing customer ids as a floating point number is just so much the wrong thing to do.  Are you sure this is not a `decimal` or `numeric` type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cast (... as bigint)
```

e.g.

```
select cast (cast (123456789 as double) as bigint);
```